Connect to wired Raspberry Pi from wireless device on different subnets
My laptop is connected wirelessly to the network with gateway 172.16.96.1 and netmask 255.255.240.0.
My Raspberry Pi is connected through wire to the network with gateway 172.16.156.1 and netmask 225.225.252.0.
Is there a way to ssh my Raspberry Pi from my laptop? (I don't have access to router configuration).

What is "the network"?

I’m voting to close this question because this seems to me to be primarily a networking question. And since RPi now uses the standard NetworkManager for network configuration, I feel the question belongs on another SE site: perhaps U&L SE, Super User, Network Engineering or Server Fault.

From your laptop, try to ping the Raspberry Pi's IP address.
If you receive a response, you should be able to SSH into the Raspberry Pi.

@liaifat85 as you can guess, if I was able to ping it and get and response or ssh into it, then I wouldn't be posting this question here at all. When I ping, I get a timeout. When I ssh, the connection is getting rejected immediately.

@Seamus posted on U&L SE. View here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/778069/connect-to-a-device-on-a-different-subnet

Good!  And I see you've now got (what looks like) a correct answer.
